# Why Vim is assembling short lines when it should just break the long ones?

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I am trying to edit a file using Vim.  However, I have just started to use this editor.

This is the text that I am willing to fix (it is in portuguese, but this fact is irrelevant to my doubt):

```
--- 
ENUM Questão 1

AREA ETHICS

Janaína é procuradora do município de Oceanópolis e atua, fora da carga horária demandada pela função, como advogada na sociedade de advogados Alfa, especializada em Direito Tributário. A profissional já foi professora na universidade estadual Beta, situada na localidade, tendo deixado o magistério há um ano, quando tomou posse como procuradora municipal.
```

As you see, the phrase starting with "Janaina é..." is too big. I am trying to make everything have 80 columns.

Hence, I did:

```
:set textwidth=80
```

And, in visual mode with all the txt selected, I did:

```
gq
```

This is the final output:

```
--- ENUM Questão 1

AREA ETHICS

Janaína é procuradora do município de Oceanópolis e atua, fora da carga horária
demandada pela função, como advogada na sociedade de advogados Alfa,
especializada em Direito Tributário. A profissional já foi professora na
universidade estadual Beta, situada na localidade, tendo deixado o magistério há
um ano, quando tomou posse como procuradora municipal.
```

The final result is close to what I want. The only problem is the change from

```
--- 
ENUM Questão 1
```

to

```
--- ENUM Questão 1
```

I thought that `:set  textwidth=80` and  `:set columns=80` were commands made to **break** lines which were too long. But, for some reason, this command is **assembling** the short line with `---` and the line with `ENUM Questão [num]`

Why is this happening? 
How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gq` can do a lot of things, depending on the `formatexpr`, `formatprg` or most possibly the `formatoptions` setting. see `:h gq`.

I would use the folloging regex:

```
:%s/.\{80}/&\r/g
```

*Note: there is also textwrap in vim, which may help you (`:set wrap`)